# basic_regex is an undefined symbo - Boost framework linker error

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, osx-yosemite

Im testing a application with boost framework. to do that i have followed

[github](https://github.com/mgrebenets/boost-xcode5-iosx) link and build framework and insert accordingly. and i set project propertise as follows

```
Language Dialect set to C++11 [-std=c++11]

C++ Standard Library set to libc++ (LLVM C++ standard library with C++11 support)

OS X deployment target 10.10
```

to avoid that error

i delete key word register
and changed my code as follows (please find the #pragma marks of following attrched code) but nothing work on me.after deleting register keyword i didnt get the deprecated warning.
but with and without that warning i got linker errors.
please help me to solove these errors.

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wdeprecated-register"

#pragma clang diagnostic pop

#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string line;
    boost::regex pat( "^Subject: (Re: |Aw: )*(.*)" );

    while (std::cin)
    {
        std::getline(std::cin, line);
        boost::smatch matches;
        if (boost::regex_match(line, matches, pat))
            std::cout << matches[2] << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[image: after building boost my file stuture]

Error log

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::do_assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int)", referenced from:
      boost::basic_regex<char, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::assign(char const*, char const*, unsigned int) in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::get_mem_block()", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::extend_stack() in main.o
      boost::re_detail::save_state_init::save_state_init(boost::re_detail::saved_state**, boost::re_detail::saved_state**) in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::put_mem_block(void*)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::save_state_init::~save_state_init() in main.o
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::unwind_extra_block(bool) in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::verify_options(unsigned int, boost::regex_constants::_match_flags)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::perl_matcher<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*>, std::__1::allocator<boost::sub_match<std::__1::__wrap_iter<char const*> > >, boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > >::match_imp() in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::raise_runtime_error(std::runtime_error const&)", referenced from:
      void boost::re_detail::raise_error<boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > >(boost::regex_traits_wrapper<boost::regex_traits<char, boost::cpp_regex_traits<char> > > const&, boost::regex_constants::error_type) in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::get_default_error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type)", referenced from:
      boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::error_string(boost::regex_constants::error_type) const in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform_primary(char const*, char const*) const in main.o
  "boost::re_detail::cpp_regex_traits_implementation<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const", referenced from:
      boost::cpp_regex_traits<char>::transform(char const*, char const*) const in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Can you add to your question the actual text of the error message?  Your screen snapshot has truncated the text.

Comment: The error you refer to in the title is just a warning. The real error is that basic_regex is an undefined symbol. You aren't linking with the library.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  i did please find edited question

Comment: @Dave i think these errors are comming due to that warning that's why i have posted that error anyway i have corrected as you sujjested thank you :)

Comment: It's unlikely the warning has anything to do with the errors (though I don't dare to say it's impossible). Are you sure you are linking with the boost regex library? Check your linker call, or, even better, post it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link boost into the project:

1. Find the "Search Paths" section in your Project Navigator.
2. There will be a subsection called: "Library Search Paths".
3. Add your installed boost's lib directory, usually something like: .../boost*/libs

Note that in this same section you should have added the main boost directory under "Header Search Paths"

**EDIT:**
You can find the getting started guide here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html

Interestingly you'll note that the [default folder](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#the-boost-distribution) structure should be: boost_1_57_0/libs Note the lack of any "i386" or "x86_64". So I'm pretty concerned for your boost setup.

Also note that `boost::regex` is a [header only file](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries). I'd do a sanity check that you are including  boost_1_57_0/boost in your "Header Search Paths".

Comment: thank you for you advice. in project propertise under valid architecture it has i386 X 86_64 . inside the compiled  boost library i could find i386 & i86_64 both folders contain libboost_system.a and libboost.a i have add paths as /Users/venushka/Desktop/boost/osx/build/i386/ and
/Users/venushka/Desktop/boost/osx/build/x86_64/ into both libarary search path and header search paths but still im having same error

Comment: @VenushkaT I realized I incorrectly typed .../boost/stage/lib I've corrected and Edited my answer and added a couple source links. Please have a look.

Comment: you're correct dude. again i'll check my boost build version.thank you and i voted your answer.

Comment: after follwed your lead- i add header search path -/Users/venushka/Desktop/boost/boost_1_54_0 & Library search path-/Users/venushka/Desktop/boost/boost_1_54_0/stage/lib thank you for you now it works

Comment: @VenushkaT Awesome I'm glad it worked for you. There's nothing more annoying than trying to get something to build or link, when all you're really trying to do is code.